# Removing snippets of code during build process Android, iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, build

I'm creating a game for both Android and iOS and I would like to include a particular third-party SDK inside my app, but only in the development build.

For example, say I have lines below to send an event with some payload:

```
Hash eventPayload = new Hash();
ThirdPartySDK.sendEvent("eventName", eventPayload);
```

I would have that code throughout my game. However, in my final production build, I would like to remove all instances of those lines for sending the events. How would I do that on both Android and iOS? Do I do it during the build process?

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 2):

Depends on exactly what you want to. If you only want code to run during debug builds it's quite simple to make that happen with this line.

```
      if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){

    }
```

If you want to get fancier, (or not go through and add this a million places), you can use proguard strip out lines like this

```
-assumenosideeffects class ThirdPartySDK{

public static void sendEvent(...);
}
```

note that proguard optimizations must be turned on

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give proguard a try!